# Find items in list where word exist and ignor special chars

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I have list of MyItems:

```
My item 
{
   string name;
   int age; 
} 

List<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>();
list.Add(new Test("name", 2));
list.Add(new Test("ŚćĄa", 4));
list.Add(new Test("May NĄmĄa bb" , 7));
list.Add(new Test("May maa cc" , 7));
```

for now with :

```
var NewList = list.Where(m => m.name.ToLower().Contains(textToSearch.ToLower())).ToList();
```

I can ignore lower and upper case, but how to ignore special chars like ĄĆŚ ,
for that when I set `textToSearch = "aa";`
 I  get item two, three and four.

But when I set `textToSearch = "ĄA";` I'd like to get only item two and four

Comment: Not really sure about your question, for `aa` your code is returning only a single item, that is the last one. and for `"ĄA"` it is returning two items, (two and four).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
list.Where(m => 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
        m.name, 
        textToSearch, 
        CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) > -1
).ToList();
```

two, three and four will be listed.